# Get View in a non Activity class and turn it in a Bitmap

Tags: android, class, android-layout, bitmap

i'm trying to get a view inside a non-activity class and transform it in a bitmap, this is my try but the view seems to have 0 as dimensions. 
My simply xml file:

**custom_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pin_events"
    android:id="@+id/rel">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/sport"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my try to get a bitmap:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rel);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: why not use `Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.resource);` to directly get the bitmap from the resource?

Comment: @EvripidisDrakos it doesn't work with layouts.

Comment: ah, you want to convert the whole view to an image? I dont know if thats possible..

Comment: Yes, i want that, i think it's possible but i need some tips on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));

view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

view.buildDrawingCache(true);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

Comment: how can I get View from a non-activity class?